# How to use `clean_names` in conjunction with `row_to_names` in the "janitor" package of R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, janitor

I have the following dataset:

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onR62.png)

What I want to do is do:

`dat %>% row_to_names(dat, row_number = 1)`

The problem is, some of the names in row number 1 are duplicates (for example there are 2 `North America` names). I don't mind this, I just want to use `clean_names` to, say, keep the duplicates but call them `North America_1` and `North America_2` so I can differentiate between them.

The current error message I'm getting is `1: In row_to_names(., t.AEC, row_number = 1) : Row 1 does not provide unique names. Consider running clean_names() after row_to_names().` but I don't know how to use `clean names` after... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the dataframe name again when using pipe.

```
library(janitor)

dat <- data.frame(V1 = c('North America', 2), 
                  V2 = c('North America', 3), 
                  V3 = c('India', 4))

dat <- dat %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% clean_names()

#  north_america north_america_2 india
#2             2               3     4
```

Since we have duplicate column names `row_to_names` function returns a warning about it.

Comment: ran ```dat %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% clean_names()``` and got the error message ```Warning message:
In row_to_names(., row_number = 1) :
  Row 1 does not provide unique names. Consider running clean_names() after row_to_names().```

Comment: @hugada It is not an error but a warning.  I already added explanation about it in the last line of the answer. It is safe to ignore the warning. If you copy the answer as it is, the changed dataframe is in `dat`.

Comment: It wasn't working on ```dat``` but I did ```dat1 <- dat %>% row_to_names (row_number= 1) %>% clean_names()``` and it worked!